# Content inside ScrollView React Native can't be scrolled

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I have a screen, there he is:

```
// Home.jsx

import {View, Text, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import Head from '../components/header/Head';
import {useSafeAreaInsets} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import Greeting from '../components/block/Greeting';
import MiniMenu from '../components/block/MiniMenu';
import ArticleMiniList from '../components/block/ArticleMiniList';
import InternetCheck from '../components/utils/InternetCheck';
import {createContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  RefreshControl,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import PointPelanggaran from '../components/block/PointPelanggaran';
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

export const RefreshContext = createContext();

function HomeScreen() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (refresh) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setRefresh(false);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [refresh]);

  return (
    <View>
      <GestureHandlerRootView>
        <RefreshContext.Provider value={{refresh, setRefresh}}>
          <View
            className="justify-center items-center space-y-10"
            style={{
              paddingTop: insets.top,
              paddingBottom: insets.bottom,
              paddingLeft: insets.left,
              paddingRight: insets.right,
            }}>
            <StatusBar
              backgroundColor="transparent"
              barStyle={'dark-content'}
              translucent={true}
            />
          </View>

          <Head name={'StudentHub'} button />

          {/* <View style={{flex: 1}}> */}
          <ScrollView
            // contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
            contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="always"
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                refreshing={refresh}
                onRefresh={() => setRefresh(true)}
              />
            }>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
              }}>
              <Greeting />
              <MiniMenu />
              <ArticleMiniList />
              <PointPelanggaran />
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
          {/* </View> */}

          <InternetCheck />
        </RefreshContext.Provider>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </View>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

I can't scroll in ScrollView even though the content is already more than the screen height.

I saw some suggestions on the internet to provide a container with the flex-1 style to wrap the ScrollView, but with that I can't see my content at all.

Without flex container :
[Can't scrolling, but the content is still visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcHKo.png)

With flex container :
[Content is not visible and absolutely can't be scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jWFA.png)